# How to convert text file to a key value pair object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, format, text-files

I have a text file which content looks like this

```
textFile = "NGGCVS3.scratch1.create,end_date="07/03/2025",pin="31742",scnum="2736289877",senum="250322602004999",SCRPREF="500",SUSP_F="0""
```

I want to convert this text file / string into a javascript object to match this format

```
const object = {
 pin: '31742',
 scnum: '2736289877',
senum: "250322602004999"

}
```

Please help me out

Comment: @JP the syntax is no JSON. Looks more like CSV.

Comment: The string doesn't make sense quotes wise. But all you need are `split` and  `indexOf`

Comment: @JP how does json parse help here?

Comment: Your nested strings will need to use the single quote (`'`) to prevent multiple strings.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier it a text file, the variable I used to represent it is just the content of the text file.

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string by comma, filter out those string without the equal symbol, filter out the "unkown" keys and finally build the desired object by using the function `Array.prototype.reduce`.

The following logic should be used for each line in the file.

```js
const textFile =  `NGGCVS3.scratch1.create,end_date="07/03/2025",pin="31742",scnum="2736289877",senum="250322602004999",SCRPREF="500",SUSP_F="0"
NGGCVS3.scratch1.create,end_date="07/03/2025",pin="31742",scnum="2736289877",senum="250322602004999",SCRPREF="500",SUSP_F="0"`;
const keys = ["pin", "scnum", "senum"];
const result = textFile.split("\n").map(line => {
    return line.split(",")
             .map(str => str.split("="))
             .filter(({length}) => length > 1)
             .map(([key, value]) => ({[key]: value.replace(/"/g, '')}))
             .filter((obj) => Object.keys(obj).some(key => keys.includes(key)))
             .reduce((a, c) => ({...a, ...c}), {})
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, what if this text file has multiple of the sample textFile content separated by semi-colon ?

Comment: @GeorgeWisdom see the updates

Comment: Thanks you sir, am very grateful  you've made my morning 